# charts.js straight lines - i cant find a solution

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So im using charts.js http://www.chartjs.org/ and im trying to make the lines between 2 dots be straight and not curvy for no apperent reason.

it right now looks like that
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK8df.png

and i want it to look like basic algebric graphs should look
like the other picture in the above link

current datasets:

```
                label: "Shop Sales",
                fillColor : "rgba(255, 89, 114, 0.6)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(51, 51, 51, 1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(255, 89, 114, 1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

and

```
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
responsive: true, scaleFontColor: "#FF5972" }
```

)};

thank you, im searching for this on the web everywhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it's been changed with v2.0. It is now `tension:0`. As of this writing the docs state it's `lineTension:0`, but that seems incorrect.

Comment: is this a recent change? , i will update the answer if it is

Comment: Most likely. I think they just released v2.0 a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: You are a saviour. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Set the option `bezierCurve` to `false`.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
      responsive: true, 
      scaleFontColor: "#FF5972",
      bezierCurve: false
    });

});
```

[It's right there in the Line Chart option list.](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart). You can also have them be curved but "stiffer" by leaving the option set and then varying the `bezierCurveTension` property.

Comment: this is amazing,but no search query for straight lines and charts.js gave me this answer. so im still suprised ;)

Comment: @user3718164 yes it kind-of hinges on knowing that the curviness comes from "bezier curves" :)

Comment: This option appears gone with the new 2.0 release. It lists a `lineTension: 0` to make straight lines, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: I found it was actually just `tension: 0`. That works.