# Chart js straight line (v1 vs v2)

Tags: chart.js

Trying to plot a straight line in Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org)

[charts.js straight lines - i cant find a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568204/charts-js-straight-lines-i-cant-find-a-solution)

The above link does not work, I suspect due to the differences between v1 and v2.

```
var options = {
        line: {
            tension: 0
        },
        bezierCurve : false
};

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type:       'line',
            data:       data,
            options:    options
            })
```

Based on docs:
http://nnnick.github.io/Chart.js/docs-v2/

The above method displays the cart as expected EXCEPT for the bezierCurve line.
I require a straight line between points and cannot get this to work.
Any pointers or references to a different JS library are appreciated.

NOTE the v1 method fails (.Line() )--

```
e.g. window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
```

Comment: Currently looking at alternatives such as: Google Chart...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. The docs say it's `lineTension:0`, but it's actually `tension:0` and that worked for me.

(http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually started using CanvasJS.com. This works pretty well and allows me to group the data differently to Google Chart. It's not free but it's worth the time.